# Project is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 win-x64. Project Service supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, netcoreapp3.1, netcoreapp3.0

After Upgrad netcoreapp3.0 to netcoreapp3.1 This Error Appear in build

Comment: Migrations can be problematic sometimes. The best way to migrate is, create a new project in .Net-Core 3.1 and import all classes/files from previous project(s). That's the fastest way to migrate without facing any bugs/issues

Comment: Please check your application whether you have installed some package or not? If installed, try to update them to the latest version. Besides, how do you migrate the application from Asp.net Core 3.0 to Asp.net Core 3.1? You could refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.0 to 3.1.